# Print n-z characters of Unicode table

Tags: code-golf, unicode

The challenge is to write a program which outputs all characters of the Unicode table from n to z range.

For code "0000" is the first in order and you must skip all blank Unicode combinations.
For example, let n = 134 and z = 300, you must save or print all unicode characters between 0134 and 0300.

The output of the program does not HAVE to output them, for example using std::cout can be used but if you have an array with all the saved characters then that still qualifies.(You don't have to print them out)

The shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by n-z range?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The program should output all Unicode characters but don't print them?

Comment: @AlexA. maybe he means it can be either function or stdout?

Comment: I mean you have to create some sort of list from "n" - "z"
For example given n=134, that would be the 134 character in Unicode or "0134"and z=300 so you would print all unicode characters between "0134" through "0300". You would then have to skip all blank characters and save them in some way.

Comment: What is meant by blank characters? Unprintables?

Comment: Any unicode character which you cannot print or don't represent any character or symbol, newline and blank spaces don't qualify, I had to change that rule once I saw a loophole...

Comment: You might want to clarify this more, especially the title.  At first I thought you were literally asking for `echo {n..z}`, e.g. "n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 0134. A number with a leading zero generally signals base 8, but U+0134 uses base 16.

Comment: Adding some examples of input and its associated output would be helpful to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth - 16 bytes

Maps `C`har-of over the range, and detects unprintables by if the string `"\x"` is inside its repr because that is how python represents unprintables like `\x00`.

```
f!}"\\x"`TCMrQvw
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f!%7D%22%5C%5Cx%22%60TCMrQvw&input=134%0A300&debug=1).

Comment: This is correct and the winner!